# How do I retrieve the Region format with Javascript on iPad or Tablet?

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, regional-settings

So for my project, I am trying to grab the users preferred regional settings from an iPad or Tablet (ex "en-us"). I tried using this line of code

`var regionSettings = navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language;`

However, all I get is "en-us" - even when I set my regional settings to "en-ca".

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link, that might help to solve your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage.language

Comment: Thats what I was using. It works on normal browsers. But if I am using an iPad, it grabs the geolocation from the router rather than the users preferred format